# Android Layout left and right align in horizontal layout

Tags: android, android-layout

I am have a ImageView and a ImageButton. I have them next to each other in a horizontal layout. I am trying to make it so that the image is left aligned on the screen, and the button is right aligned. I have tried setting gravity but it doesnt seem to make a difference. Where am I going wrong?

```
<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" 
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:src="@drawable/short_logo" />

    <ImageButton
        android:id="@+id/terminateSeed"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="right"
        android:background="@null"
        android:src="@drawable/unregister_icon" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 33, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        style="?android:attr/buttonStyleSmall"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:text="Button" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: the thing is you should always tend to answer the question in the way with which it was asked, it could have been done easily by using a LinearLayout by setting weightSum property...

Comment: yes you are right @mirroredAbstraction 
but try to give your best.
and LinearLayout not much useful for real development that's y i suggest him to use Relative one...

Comment: LinearLayout's are great for instances where you don't want to have to re-implement the onMeasure and onLayout functionality within a custom RelativeLayout.

Answer (score 12):

Use...

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="1.0" >

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"
    android:layout_marginRight="80dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:gravity="left"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/terminateSeed"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="0.5"
    android:gravity="right"
    android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: @Agarwal, why do you think so, did you try it?

Comment: it works very well and beside this...this should be the correct answer...because the question was...how to solve the problem with an LinearLayout...not to offer alternatives with RelativeLayout...i know also with RelativeLayout...but i need with LinearLayout...This must be the correct answer

Comment: This is definitely the right answer to the question! Relative layout is just an alternative. Just one question, why are you using  android:layout_marginLeft="80dp"?

Answer (score 3):

Use This example if you want to use LinearLayout without giving Weight

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
       />

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_vertical"
        android:gravity="right"
        />
    </LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout 
android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"

>

<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageView1"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="left"

    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:src="@drawable/short_logo" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/terminateSeed"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:background="@null"
    android:src="@drawable/unregister_icon" />
</RelativeLayout >
```

Answer (score 0):

Make `imageview` and `imagebutton` `wrap_content` and set `layout_gravity` to left and right accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

a `RelativeLayout` would solve your problem with a snap, but if you still insist on using LinearLayout (just because we're badass and do things the hard way), you do it like this:

Your parent LinearLayout is fill-parent, left-aligned, and horizontally oriented,
and contains your ImageView, and another LinearLayout.

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="left"
```

Second LinearLayout is fill-parent, right-aligned, and horizontally oriented, and contains your ImageButton.

```
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:gravity="right"
```

Answer (score 0):

Another approach for `LinearLayout`, using `layout_weight` and `gravity`:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="BUTTON 1"/>
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="BUTTON 2" />
</LinearLayout>
```